# Taking the Average of Integers (j+k)/2 when stack there is an Overflow

Tags: java, overflow, average

If there is an `int j = Integer.MAX_VALUE` and an `int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE` how can I compute the average (j+k)/2 so that the `result = Integer.MAX_VALUE` without causing an overflow.

Comment: same as (j/2) + (k/2)

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you post that as an answer instead of as a comment so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Comment: Is it not better to just use long if you're reaching `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: @Gendarme I needed an answer that would only use int! But yes long would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `(j+k)/2` is the same as `(j/2) + (k/2)`

**Correction** as per bilalba

```
    int j = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int k = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int res = (j/2) + (k/2) + (j%2 & k%2);
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: This would actually give the wrong answer. It will give Integer.MAX_VALUE-1.

Comment: You are correct @bilalba. This solution works for most cases, but not for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could write, `(j/2) + (k/2)`. Here is an example for two small numbers `10`, and `11`, using the typical method.

```
10 + 11 = 21
21/2 = 10.5
```

Now the other way:

```
10/2 = 5;
11/2 = 5.5;
5.5+5 = 10.5;
```

As you can see here, either way you will get the same result, except you will not have to add the numbers, because that would result in overflow as you mentioned.

*EDIT*

I just realized this is wrong, and will only work with even numbers. Here is optimal solution (works for all numbers).

```
(j/2) + (k/2) + (j%2 && k%2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`j + (i - j) / 2` is equivalent to `(i + j) / 2` and won't overflow in this case (when difference between numbers is small). In cases where this expression overflows, `(i + j) / 2` will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
(j/2) + (k/2) + ((j%2) && (k%2))
```

((j%2) && (k%2)) is to cater for both odd numbers case. If j,k= 1, then j/2+k/2 only would give you 0.

This is because 0.5 will be floored to the next smallest integer which is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but your code does not compile.  See my answer

Comment: How exactly would you code this @bilalba. I think i'm understanding what your trying to say, but i'm not quite sure what you mean by `+ (j%2 && k%2)` because as @Scary Wombat says, the code does not compile

Comment: @Kekis2014 I have made a correction to my answer, the correct code should be `(j/2) + (k/2) + (j%2 & k%2);`  That is only one `&`